# Leader died mid-conversation, will the ambassador come back next year?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My Countess and the Dwarven Liason were almost done negotiating the trade agreement for next year when the former died in a [horrible minecart accident](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Unfortunate_accident) (that I *didn't* intend to happen, I *swear*), causing the "A diplomat left unhappy" message.

They'd already finished discussing import and export details, and all that was missing was the final "Until next year" message.

My question is twofold. Well, three now that I think of it:

1. **Will the liason be back next year**? I kind of like being able to negotiate to have extra amounts of specific goods sent over, especially now that I've run out of things to hunt for leather and meat.
2. **Will the negotiated trade agreements be honored?** They are currently listed in the civilizations overview, so I hope so...
3. **Will I be allowed to appoint another count/countess?** As nobles went this one actually wasn't terrible and I have a few possible candidates that might also do a good job...

Comment: I don't have time for a properly formatted answer, but the answer to all 3 questions is yes. Though the trader leaving unhappy increases the chance of that civilization hating you and then seiging you, it won't happen unless you've previously pissed them off.

Comment: Well, I bought up almost their entire inventory in exchange for two barrels of my best food, does that count?

Comment: Value is based off what they came with vs what they left with. So long as they left with a higher value than what they came with, it will reflect positively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expedition Leaders are elected in the game at random, so the Expedition Leader should be replaced. The answers to all 3 are yes.